# Can not connect with mysql database in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

i am trying to connect with mysql database after run the web app there is an error like:
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report
message Internal Server Error
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysqluser=root'

root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysqluser=root'

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0

My JSP code is:

```
`<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
```

`<%`

String fname = request.getParameter("fname");

```
`String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
`String email = request.getParameter("email");
`String user = request.getParameter("uname"); 
`String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
```

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
Connection con = `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"+ "user=root");`
Statement st = con.createStatement();

```
`int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(first_name, last_name,email, uname, pass) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pwd + "')");
`if (i > 0)
`{
 `out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<ahref='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
`} 
`else {
    `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

`}`
%>
`

My database does not have any password.
I was establish my connectivity in netbeans by following steps:
Step 1: Service tab
Step 2: Right click on Databases and select New Connection...
Step 3: Follow the steps. 
Test connection was successfully then finish.
I am using linux Fedora 20 OS

Comment: A good way to start, would be to move all your business logic from your JSP (which is only intended for UI representation) to servlets. A next part, since you have a full stack trace (which you are not showing) looking at that might help shed more light on the issue.

Comment: while getting connection dont u need to add username and pass of ur mysql database server?

Comment: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"+ "user=root")
this is the problamatic line;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"+ "user=root");` is wrong because:

Concatenation of `url` with `"user=root"` will result in the String: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqluser=root` which is defenitely wrong. In the url, you are missing database name (if it is mysql then you have a problem with naming it so and i advice you to change your db name).

**Solution:**

Define variables for the url, user and password separately (even if password is not set, you must provide it as empty string). See the following code:

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName";
String user="root";
String password="";

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. It's a bad idea to write your db logic in the jsp. It's better to externalize the code for db management in other class, and use it to get the corresponding connection.

P.P.S. Don't forget to manage your db resources after you have done with them (i'm talking about a finally block where you are closing Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet) to release the used resources and avoid memory leaks. It's a good idea to write a separated method which takes these arguments and checks them for null, and if condition is true, the corresponding resource will be closed.

Comment: @sanketkaranjule if this answer have resolved your problem, please mark this answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the password argument...even if you log with no password but add it with empt string... And check if you added the library of mysql to tomcat or glassfish if you are using

Comment: welcome to stack i know ur repo didnt allowed to post comment. but while entering mske sure to add some code snippet for better understanding of the asker as it seems the asker is also quite new to stack

Comment: Okay i will next time...tanks in advance